# BizTalk Halt and Clear all Rule Firings

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

The following is essentially the rule:

```
If the node does not exist then do not continue with the next rule.

If the node does exist then continue with the next rule.
```

This is accomplished by setting the priority on the rules and then by `Halt and clear all rule firings` - on the initial check for nodes existing.

I've tested in the rule composer and the first rule is fired.  However, this doesn't stop the next rule from firing.  It continues and fails because obviously the node is not found in the xml.

Has anybody any ideas why it would continue even though the action specifically say's `halt and clear all rule firings`?

Is there some kind of BizTalk - reset the host instance, restart visual studio trick?

I've done this in another rule and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the engine runs all the rules at once.  I've managed to get around the problem by using specific XPath for the rules.